# NSArray Getting Out Of Order

Tags: ios, nsarray, nsdictionary, plist, nsmutabledictionary

I use a PLIST to populate a TableView in my app.  I want the TableView to be in order of how items were added, due to needing a good way to edit it later on, so the indexPath.row will match up with the indexPath of the PLIST.  I get the TableView populated by going from the PLIST to NSDictionary to NSArray.  The issue is that the TableView keeps listing everything in alphabetical order and not the order it was listed

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *plistPath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:self.selectedCountry];
    _plist = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile: plistPath];
    _content = [_plist allKeys];
```

Comment: Dictionaries have no order. Getting all of the keys will give you an array is no particular order.

Comment: If you really want get the keys as an array then why not use the Array in first place in plist. Create an array of strings in the plist and put all the keys in it.